# How cross coupled gate works?

Tags: logic-gates

How do this two gate able to give an output if in the first place they both doesn't have a second output... in which will be the input of the other...

Both cannot get a second input because they don't have a second input themselves to provide an input to the other...

[image]

Conversation:

Gate 1: Hey gate 2, I'll give you your second input... oh wait, I don't have my second input... I can't provide you your second input.. you don't have a second input as well that I need, now we're stuck.

Gate 2: I know right.

Comment: Guess the output, and then keep calculating the outputs until they either stabilise on a value, or you find they are oscillating (i.e. you have get back to an output value you have seen before).

Comment: A gate does not always need two known inputs to produce a known output. For example, if one input to a NAND gate is 0, the output is 1 regardless of the state of the other input.

Comment: @DaveTweed In the diagram I showed, a NAND gate has a single input of 0, yet it also outputs 0 ?

Comment: I don't know where that diagram came from, but obviously, that's wrong. If you look at the truth table for a NAND gate, there's only one way it can produce a 0, and that's if both inputs are 1.

Comment: @DaveTweed looking on gate 1 of the diagram above, since the input is 0, the output should be 1?

Comment: How many times do I need to say it? YES!